# Integral face ring of the triangulation of a sphere

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

The integral face ring of a (finite) simplicial complex $K$ on $m$ vertices is the quotient ring

$$\mathbb{Z}[K]=\mathbb{Z}[v_1,...,v_m]/\mathcal{I}_K$$

where $\mathcal{I}_K$ is the ideal generated by the square free monomials $v_{i_1} v_{i_2}\dots v_{i_n}$ where $I=\{i_1,...,i_n\}$ is a minimal missing face of $K$. That is, $I \notin K$, but for all $J \subsetneq I$, $J \in K$.

It was proven by Stanley that the core of a simplicial complex is a generalised homology sphere (that is, a homology manifold with the homology of a sphere) if and only if the face ring is Gorenstein.

Is there a similar characterisation of when $K$ is a genuine triangulation of a sphere, in terms of the algebra of $K$?

Comment: My memory is that there is a theorem that it is uncomputable whether a given simplicial complex is a triangulation of an $n$-sphere, for $n \geq 5$. So any corresponding criterion would be an incomputable criterion in commutative algebra, and I don't know any of those.

Comment: IIRC there is an issue where taking a cone over a complex does not change whether the face ring is Gorenstein, so what you said about what Stanley proved is not quite true - although it's morally correct.

Comment: Ah, excuse me. I'll correct that. It should be that the core of $K$ is a GHS if and only if its face ring is Gorenstein

Comment: For a reference to the undecidability of whether a simplicial complex triangulates a sphere, see Theorem 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3848.pdf.